# Amazon Payfort .NET Integration using SDK

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, payfort

I am trying to test amazon payfort SDK for .net as I have to use it in my main website but unable to do so as after providing all the required information mentioned it's still not running. Required information are as follows:

"AccessCode": "**********",
"MerchantIdentifier": "**********",
"RequestShaPhrase": "**********",
"ResponseShaPhrase": "**********",
"ShaType": "Sha256"

Only error I am getting is technical problem with a code 0006 which is very weird as there is no information present at all about this.

If someone has faced this issue earlier please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```json
{
  "SdkConfiguration": {
    "Environment": "Test",//or production
    "AccessCode": "",
    "MerchantIdentifier": "",
    "RequestShaPhrase": "",
    "ResponseShaPhrase": "",
    "ShaType": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**